# How can I get all text after a given phrase?

Tags: php, string

How can I get everything from `$string` after `"<div class='partFive'>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
$prefix = "<div class='partFive'>";
$index = strpos($string, $prefix) + strlen($prefix);
$result = substr($string, $index);
```

obviously you don't have to re-calculate the "strlen" part of it each time if the $prefix value is static.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need everything after `<div class='partFive'>` or everything in that DOM element?

I'm assuming you mean you want to grab everything in that DOM element, and the easiest way would be to grab it by using [`Zend_Dom`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html).

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$results = $dom->query('div.partFive');

foreach ($results as $result) {
    // $result is a DOMElement
}
```

Comment: He's only asking about strings.

Comment: Yes, everyone always asks about processing HTML with strings and regex. Doesn't make it the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myString = strstr($string, "<div class='partFive'>");
```

Comment: This will include `"<div class='partFix'>"`. He wants everything after.

Comment: is not that hard, simply add a substr then

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the part you don't want, like so:

```
$myString = str_replace("<div class='partFive'>","",$string);
```

Comment: What if the "<div class='partFive'>" was nested somehow, and the $string did not start with it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear that the string does not start with that